# Android application stops on creating a database

Tags: android, sqlite

My application crashes down as I create a database. Here's my code

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_order);

    //Step 1:Create DB and table
    final SQLiteDatabase 
 db=openOrCreateDatabase("Test_db",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    String c_query="create table if not exists clients(sname text,add 
 text,order text,price text, ddate text)";
    db.execSQL(c_query);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"DB and Table 
  created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //Step 2: Object Declaration

    final EditText sname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final EditText add=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText order=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final EditText price=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    final EditText ddate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    //Step 4:Click event of button

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Step 5: get the value of Objects

            String ssname=sname.getText().toString();
            String sadd=add.getText().toString();

            String sorder=order.getText().toString();
            String sprice=price.getText().toString();
            String sddate=ddate.getText().toString();

            //Step 6: Execute Insert query

            String i_query= "insert into clients values ('"+ssname+"','"+sadd+"','"+sorder+"','"+sprice+"','"+sddate+"')";
            db.execSQL(i_query);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Record 
  Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });



}
```

Comment: Show us your LogCat (add to your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your query with the below-mentioned query and it will not crash.

String c_query="create table if not exists clients(sname text,'add' 
 text,'order' text,price text, ddate text)";

Answer (score 1):

`add` and `order` are [sqlite keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) and cannot be used as column names without quoting. Consider renaming those columns.